# changing class of checkboxes on load if checked

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I am using a Jquery Accordion. I have inside each div 10 or more checkboxes. I am using Jquery to toggle the class and change the BG-color. I am also saving the status of each checkbox into a database. When the page loads again, it does show the correct status for each checkbox, but does not change the class, I believe because this happens on change. Also, I need to be able to change the header color if all the checkboxes in a div are checked. The Jquery I am using right now is

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
$(this).closest('fieldset')
    .removeClass('bg-info', this.checked) // remove the bg-info once clicked
    .toggleClass('bg-warning', !this.checked) // show warning when un-checked
    .toggleClass('bg-success', this.checked); // show success when checked
```

});

and the html is like

```
<div id="Accordion1">
<h3 class = "col-lg-12 text-center bg-warning "><a href="#">Step 1 </a></h3>

<div id= "acc1">
   <form role="form" action="pdi-run.php" method="post" name='details'>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="1" onClick="checkval(this)" <?php echo $boxes[1] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Inspected 
     </fieldset>  

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="2" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[2] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>All 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="3" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[3] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>All 
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="4" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[4] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Trunk 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="5" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[5] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>aligns 
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="6" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[6] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>present
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="7" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[7] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>cracks
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="8" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[8] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Front 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="9" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[9] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Weather
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="10"  onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[10] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Key 
     </fieldset> 

     <textarea class= "form-control notes" name="notes[]" data-num="1" onChange="getVal(this)" placeholder = "If any of the above items were etc."><?php echo $notes[1] ? $notes[1] : '' ?></textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with just jquery and css, if you're saving these in a database, then you will need to get this data out again using PHP, for example, and then apply a check and add a class that way.

Comment: @Karl I think you misunderstand; "I am also saving the status of each checkbox into a database. When the page loads again, it does show the correct status for each checkbox, but does not change the class". He's not confused about HTML statelessness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sounds simple enough. You just want to "refresh" the class state of the fieldset on init, not just when changed.

```
function refreshCheckboxes() {
$(this).closest('fieldset')
    // Your second parameter, I believe, wasn't actually doing anything
    .removeClass('bg-info');
    .toggleClass('bg-warning', !this.checked) // show warning when un-checked
    .toggleClass('bg-success', this.checked); // show success when checked
}
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', refreshCheckboxes).each(refreshCheckboxes);
```

Comment: this pretty much worked. Now everything that is not checked shows as warning, instead of info, but I am just gonna drop the warning part and have it either be info or success. thx. I will write the second part of this question up as a different question if I cannot get it.